# Issues With org-ql and Searching Based On Property Inheritence

Tags: org-mode, search, org-ql

I would like to be able to search for all TODO's with a property of `FEATURE_NUM`, and that property is inherited in my TODO's.

Here's what I have in my `init.el` to make that property inheritable:

```
(setq org-use-property-inheritance
      (list "FEATURE_NUM"))
```

I then have a TODO tree that looks like thes:

```
* Task List
  :PROPERTIES:
  :FEATURE_NUM: 12345
  :END:
** TODO Go over the API design docs                      :c_coding:
```

When I search using `org-sparse-tree` for an element with that property name and value, that TODO is returned.

I then looked in the `org-ql` docs regarding property searches and saw that I need to use a custom predicate if I want to search for properties using inheritance. I therefore created a query like this:

```
(org-ql-block '(and
                (todo)
                (property "FEATURE_NUM")
                (> 0 (string-to-number (org-entry-get (point) "FEATURE_NUM" 'inherit)))
                ))
```

I'm trying to evaluate each TODO and see if it has that property name and the value is > 0. 
However, this query always returns `nil`.

Can anyone see what I'm missing? According to the docs this seems to be the right way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh duh, I guess I was trying to make things too complicated. This ended up working:

```
(org-ql-block '(and
                (todo)
                (org-entry-get (point) "FEATURE_NUM" 'inherit)))
```

Since I'm using the `org-entry-get` function I don't need the `property` predicate.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (assuming that it answered your question :-) ).